# jquery countdown script not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an jquery countdown script, but it seems that it wont update every second, so you have to update the webpage everytime you want to know the new countdown time. can you please help me to change it so it perhaps updates automatic?

```
(function ($) {
function Countdown() {
    this.regional = [];
    this.regional[''] = {
        labels: ['Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds'],
        labels1: ['Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second'],
        compactLabels: ['y', 'm', 'w', 'd'],
        whichLabels: null,
        digits: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
        timeSeparator: ':',
        isRTL: false
    };
    this._defaults = {
        until: null,
        since: null,
        timezone: null,
        serverSync: null,
        format: 'dHMS',
        layout: '',
        compact: false,
        significant: 0,
        description: '',
        expiryUrl: '',
        expiryText: '',
        alwaysExpire: false,
        onExpiry: null,
        onTick: null,
        tickInterval: 1
    };
    $.extend(this._defaults, this.regional['']);
    this._serverSyncs = [];

    function timerCallBack(a) {
        var b = (a || new Date().getTime());
        if (b - d >= 1000) {
            x._updateTargets();
            d = b
        }
        c(timerCallBack)
    }
    var c = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || null;
    var d = 0;
    if (!c || $.noRequestAnimationFrame) {
        $.noRequestAnimationFrame = null;
        setInterval(function () {
            x._updateTargets()
        }, 980)
    } else {
        d = window.mozAnimationStartTime || new Date().getTime();
        c(timerCallBack)
    }
}
var Y = 0;
var O = 1;
var W = 2;
var D = 3;
var H = 4;
var M = 5;
var S = 6;
$.extend(Countdown.prototype, {
    markerClassName: 'hasCountdown',
    propertyName: 'countdown',
    _rtlClass: 'countdown_rtl',
    _sectionClass: 'countdown_section',
    _amountClass: 'countdown_amount',
    _rowClass: 'countdown_row',
    _holdingClass: 'countdown_holding',
    _showClass: 'countdown_show',
    _descrClass: 'countdown_descr',
    _timerTargets: [],
    setDefaults: function (a) {
        this._resetExtraLabels(this._defaults, a);
        $.extend(this._defaults, a || {})
    },
    UTCDate: function (a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i) {
        if (typeof b == 'object' && b.constructor == Date) {
            i = b.getMilliseconds();
            h = b.getSeconds();
            g = b.getMinutes();
            f = b.getHours();
            e = b.getDate();
            c = b.getMonth();
            b = b.getFullYear()
        }
        var d = new Date();
        d.setUTCFullYear(b);
        d.setUTCDate(1);
        d.setUTCMonth(c || 0);
        d.setUTCDate(e || 1);
        d.setUTCHours(f || 0);
        d.setUTCMinutes((g || 0) - (Math.abs(a) < 30 ? a * 60 : a));
        d.setUTCSeconds(h || 0);
        d.setUTCMilliseconds(i || 0);
        return d
    },
    periodsToSeconds: function (a) {
        return a[0] * 31557600 + a[1] * 2629800 + a[2] * 604800 + a[3] * 86400 + a[4] * 3600 + a[5] * 60 + a[6]
    },
    _attachPlugin: function (a, b) {
        a = $(a);
        if (a.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
            return
        }
        var c = {
            options: $.extend({}, this._defaults),
            _periods: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        };
        a.addClass(this.markerClassName).data(this.propertyName, c);
        this._optionPlugin(a, b)
    },
    _addTarget: function (a) {
        if (!this._hasTarget(a)) {
            this._timerTargets.push(a)
        }
    },
    _hasTarget: function (a) {
        return ($.inArray(a, this._timerTargets) > -1)
    },
    _removeTarget: function (b) {
        this._timerTargets = $.map(this._timerTargets, function (a) {
            return (a == b ? null : a)
        })
    },
    _updateTargets: function () {
        for (var i = this._timerTargets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            this._updateCountdown(this._timerTargets[i])
        }
    },
    _optionPlugin: function (a, b, c) {
        a = $(a);
        var d = a.data(this.propertyName);
        if (!b || (typeof b == 'string' && c == null)) {
            var e = b;
            b = (d || {}).options;
            return (b && e ? b[e] : b)
        }
        if (!a.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
            return
        }
        b = b || {};
        if (typeof b == 'string') {
            var e = b;
            b = {};
            b[e] = c
        }
        this._resetExtraLabels(d.options, b);
        $.extend(d.options, b);
        this._adjustSettings(a, d);
        var f = new Date();
        if ((d._since && d._since < f) || (d._until && d._until > f)) {
            this._addTarget(a)
        }
        this._updateCountdown(a, d)
    },
    _updateCountdown: function (a, b) {
        var c = $(a);
        b = b || c.data(this.propertyName);
        if (!b) {
            return
        }
        c.html(this._generateHTML(b)).toggleClass(this._rtlClass, b.options.isRTL);
        if ($.isFunction(b.options.onTick)) {
            var d = b._hold != 'lap' ? b._periods : this._calculatePeriods(b, b._show, b.options.significant, new Date());
            if (b.options.tickInterval == 1 || this.periodsToSeconds(d) % b.options.tickInterval == 0) {
                b.options.onTick.apply(a, [d])
            }
        }
        var e = b._hold != 'pause' && (b._since ? b._now.getTime() < b._since.getTime() : b._now.getTime() >= b._until.getTime());
        if (e && !b._expiring) {
            b._expiring = true;
            if (this._hasTarget(a) || b.options.alwaysExpire) {
                this._removeTarget(a);
                if ($.isFunction(b.options.onExpiry)) {
                    b.options.onExpiry.apply(a, [])
                }
                if (b.options.expiryText) {
                    var f = b.options.layout;
                    b.options.layout = b.options.expiryText;
                    this._updateCountdown(a, b);
                    b.options.layout = f
                }
                if (b.options.expiryUrl) {
                    window.location = b.options.expiryUrl
                }
            }
            b._expiring = false
        } else if (b._hold == 'pause') {
            this._removeTarget(a)
        }
        c.data(this.propertyName, b)
    },
    _resetExtraLabels: function (a, b) {
        var c = false;
        for (var n in b) {
            if (n != 'whichLabels' && n.match(/[Ll]abels/)) {
                c = true;
                break
            }
        }
        if (c) {
            for (var n in a) {
                if (n.match(/[Ll]abels[02-9]/)) {
                    a[n] = null
                }
            }
        }
    },
    _adjustSettings: function (a, b) {
        var c;
        var d = 0;
        var e = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this._serverSyncs.length; i++) {
            if (this._serverSyncs[i][0] == b.options.serverSync) {
                e = this._serverSyncs[i][1];
                break
            }
        }
        if (e != null) {
            d = (b.options.serverSync ? e : 0);
            c = new Date()
        } else {
            var f = ($.isFunction(b.options.serverSync) ? b.options.serverSync.apply(a, []) : null);
            c = new Date();
            d = (f ? c.getTime() - f.getTime() : 0);
            this._serverSyncs.push([b.options.serverSync, d])
        }
        var g = b.options.timezone;
        g = (g == null ? -c.getTimezoneOffset() : g);
        b._since = b.options.since;
        if (b._since != null) {
            b._since = this.UTCDate(g, this._determineTime(b._since, null));
            if (b._since && d) {
                b._since.setMilliseconds(b._since.getMilliseconds() + d)
            }
        }
        b._until = this.UTCDate(g, this._determineTime(b.options.until, c));
        if (d) {
            b._until.setMilliseconds(b._until.getMilliseconds() + d)
        }
        b._show = this._determineShow(b)
    },
    _destroyPlugin: function (a) {
        a = $(a);
        if (!a.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
            return
        }
        this._removeTarget(a[0]);
        a.removeClass(this.markerClassName).empty().removeData(this.propertyName)
    },
    _pausePlugin: function (a) {
        this._hold(a, 'pause')
    },
    _lapPlugin: function (a) {
        this._hold(a, 'lap')
    },
    _resumePlugin: function (a) {
        this._hold(a, null)
    },
    _hold: function (a, b) {
        var c = $.data(a, this.propertyName);
        if (c) {
            if (c._hold == 'pause' && !b) {
                c._periods = c._savePeriods;
                var d = (c._since ? '-' : '+');
                c[c._since ? '_since' : '_until'] = this._determineTime(d + c._periods[0] + 'y' + d + c._periods[1] + 'o' + d + c._periods[2] + 'w' + d + c._periods[3] + 'd' + d + c._periods[4] + 'h' + d + c._periods[5] + 'm' + d + c._periods[6] + 's');
                this._addTarget(a)
            }
            c._hold = b;
            c._savePeriods = (b == 'pause' ? c._periods : null);
            $.data(a, this.propertyName, c);
            this._updateCountdown(a, c)
        }
    },
    _getTimesPlugin: function (a) {
        var b = $.data(a, this.propertyName);
        return (!b ? null : (!b._hold ? b._periods : this._calculatePeriods(b, b._show, b.options.significant, new Date())))
    },
    _determineTime: function (k, l) {
        var m = function (a) {
            var b = new Date();
            b.setTime(b.getTime() + a * 1000);
            return b
        };
        var n = function (a) {
            a = a.toLowerCase();
            var b = new Date();
            var c = b.getFullYear();
            var d = b.getMonth();
            var e = b.getDate();
            var f = b.getHours();
            var g = b.getMinutes();
            var h = b.getSeconds();
            var i = /([+-]?[0-9]+)\s*(s|m|h|d|w|o|y)?/g;
            var j = i.exec(a);
            while (j) {
                switch (j[2] || 's') {
                    case 's':
                        h += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                        break;
                    case 'm':
                        g += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                        break;
                    case 'h':
                        f += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        e += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                        break;
                    case 'w':
                        e += parseInt(j[1], 10) * 7;
                        break;
                    case 'o':
                        d += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                        e = Math.min(e, x._getDaysInMonth(c, d));
                        break;
                    case 'y':
                        c += parseInt(j[1], 10);
                        e = Math.min(e, x._getDaysInMonth(c, d));
                        break
                }
                j = i.exec(a)
            }
            return new Date(c, d, e, f, g, h, 0)
        };
        var o = (k == null ? l : (typeof k == 'string' ? n(k) : (typeof k == 'number' ? m(k) : k)));
        if (o) o.setMilliseconds(0);
        return o
    },
    _getDaysInMonth: function (a, b) {
        return 32 - new Date(a, b, 32).getDate()
    },
    _normalLabels: function (a) {
        return a
    },
    _generateHTML: function (c) {
        var d = this;
        c._periods = (c._hold ? c._periods : this._calculatePeriods(c, c._show, c.options.significant, new Date()));
        var e = false;
        var f = 0;
        var g = c.options.significant;
        var h = $.extend({}, c._show);
        for (var i = Y; i <= S; i++) {
            e |= (c._show[i] == '?' && c._periods[i] > 0);
            h[i] = (c._show[i] == '?' && !e ? null : c._show[i]);
            f += (h[i] ? 1 : 0);
            g -= (c._periods[i] > 0 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        var j = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
        for (var i = S; i >= Y; i--) {
            if (c._show[i]) {
                if (c._periods[i]) {
                    j[i] = true
                } else {
                    j[i] = g > 0;
                    g--
                }
            }
        }
        var k = (c.options.compact ? c.options.compactLabels : c.options.labels);
        var l = c.options.whichLabels || this._normalLabels;
        var m = function (a) {
            var b = c.options['compactLabels' + l(c._periods[a])];
            return (h[a] ? d._translateDigits(c, c._periods[a]) + (b ? b[a] : k[a]) + ' ' : '')
        };
        var n = function (a) {
            var b = c.options['labels' + l(c._periods[a])];
            return ((!c.options.significant && h[a]) || (c.options.significant && j[a]) ? '<span class="' + x._sectionClass + '">' + '<span class="' + x._amountClass + '">' + d._translateDigits(c, c._periods[a]) + '</span><br/>' + (b ? b[a] : k[a]) + '</span>' : '')
        };
        return (c.options.layout ? this._buildLayout(c, h, c.options.layout, c.options.compact, c.options.significant, j) : ((c.options.compact ? '<span class="' + this._rowClass + ' ' + this._amountClass + (c._hold ? ' ' + this._holdingClass : '') + '">' + m(Y) + m(O) + m(W) + m(D) + (h[H] ? this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 2) : '') + (h[M] ? (h[H] ? c.options.timeSeparator : '') + this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 2) : '') + (h[S] ? (h[H] || h[M] ? c.options.timeSeparator : '') + this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 2) : '') : '<span class="' + this._rowClass + ' ' + this._showClass + (c.options.significant || f) + (c._hold ? ' ' + this._holdingClass : '') + '">' + n(Y) + n(O) + n(W) + n(D) + n(H) + n(M) + n(S)) + '</span>' + (c.options.description ? '<span class="' + this._rowClass + ' ' + this._descrClass + '">' + c.options.description + '</span>' : '')))
    },
    _buildLayout: function (c, d, e, f, g, h) {
        var j = c.options[f ? 'compactLabels' : 'labels'];
        var k = c.options.whichLabels || this._normalLabels;
        var l = function (a) {
            return (c.options[(f ? 'compactLabels' : 'labels') + k(c._periods[a])] || j)[a]
        };
        var m = function (a, b) {
            return c.options.digits[Math.floor(a / b) % 10]
        };
        var o = {
            desc: c.options.description,
            sep: c.options.timeSeparator,
            yl: l(Y),
            yn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[Y], 1),
            ynn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[Y], 2),
            ynnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[Y], 3),
            y1: m(c._periods[Y], 1),
            y10: m(c._periods[Y], 10),
            y100: m(c._periods[Y], 100),
            y1000: m(c._periods[Y], 1000),
            ol: l(O),
            on: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[O], 1),
            onn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[O], 2),
            onnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[O], 3),
            o1: m(c._periods[O], 1),
            o10: m(c._periods[O], 10),
            o100: m(c._periods[O], 100),
            o1000: m(c._periods[O], 1000),
            wl: l(W),
            wn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[W], 1),
            wnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[W], 2),
            wnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[W], 3),
            w1: m(c._periods[W], 1),
            w10: m(c._periods[W], 10),
            w100: m(c._periods[W], 100),
            w1000: m(c._periods[W], 1000),
            dl: l(D),
            dn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[D], 1),
            dnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[D], 2),
            dnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[D], 3),
            d1: m(c._periods[D], 1),
            d10: m(c._periods[D], 10),
            d100: m(c._periods[D], 100),
            d1000: m(c._periods[D], 1000),
            hl: l(H),
            hn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 1),
            hnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 2),
            hnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[H], 3),
            h1: m(c._periods[H], 1),
            h10: m(c._periods[H], 10),
            h100: m(c._periods[H], 100),
            h1000: m(c._periods[H], 1000),
            ml: l(M),
            mn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 1),
            mnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 2),
            mnnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[M], 3),
            m1: m(c._periods[M], 1),
            m10: m(c._periods[M], 10),
            m100: m(c._periods[M], 100),
            m1000: m(c._periods[M], 1000),
            sl: l(S),
            sn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 1),
            snn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 2),
            snnn: this._minDigits(c, c._periods[S], 3),
            s1: m(c._periods[S], 1),
            s10: m(c._periods[S], 10),
            s100: m(c._periods[S], 100),
            s1000: m(c._periods[S], 1000)
        };
        var p = e;
        for (var i = Y; i <= S; i++) {
            var q = 'yowdhms'.charAt(i);
            var r = new RegExp('\\{' + q + '<\\}(.*)\\{' + q + '>\\}', 'g');
            p = p.replace(r, ((!g && d[i]) || (g && h[i]) ? '$1' : ''))
        }
        $.each(o, function (n, v) {
            var a = new RegExp('\\{' + n + '\\}', 'g');
            p = p.replace(a, v)
        });
        return p
    },
    _minDigits: function (a, b, c) {
        b = '' + b;
        if (b.length >= c) {
            return this._translateDigits(a, b)
        }
        b = '0000000000' + b;
        return this._translateDigits(a, b.substr(b.length - c))
    },
    _translateDigits: function (b, c) {
        return ('' + c).replace(/[0-9]/g, function (a) {
            return b.options.digits[a]
        })
    },
    _determineShow: function (a) {
        var b = a.options.format;
        var c = [];
        c[Y] = (b.match('y') ? '?' : (b.match('Y') ? '!' : null));
        c[O] = (b.match('o') ? '?' : (b.match('O') ? '!' : null));
        c[W] = (b.match('w') ? '?' : (b.match('W') ? '!' : null));
        c[D] = (b.match('d') ? '?' : (b.match('D') ? '!' : null));
        c[H] = (b.match('h') ? '?' : (b.match('H') ? '!' : null));
        c[M] = (b.match('m') ? '?' : (b.match('M') ? '!' : null));
        c[S] = (b.match('s') ? '?' : (b.match('S') ? '!' : null));
        return c
    },
    _calculatePeriods: function (c, d, e, f) {
        c._now = f;
        c._now.setMilliseconds(0);
        var g = new Date(c._now.getTime());
        if (c._since) {
            if (f.getTime() < c._since.getTime()) {
                c._now = f = g
            } else {
                f = c._since
            }
        } else {
            g.setTime(c._until.getTime());
            if (f.getTime() > c._until.getTime()) {
                c._now = f = g
            }
        }
        var h = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        if (d[Y] || d[O]) {
            var i = x._getDaysInMonth(f.getFullYear(), f.getMonth());
            var j = x._getDaysInMonth(g.getFullYear(), g.getMonth());
            var k = (g.getDate() == f.getDate() || (g.getDate() >= Math.min(i, j) && f.getDate() >= Math.min(i, j)));
            var l = function (a) {
                return (a.getHours() * 60 + a.getMinutes()) * 60 + a.getSeconds()
            };
            var m = Math.max(0, (g.getFullYear() - f.getFullYear()) * 12 + g.getMonth() - f.getMonth() + ((g.getDate() < f.getDate() && !k) || (k && l(g) < l(f)) ? -1 : 0));
            h[Y] = (d[Y] ? Math.floor(m / 12) : 0);
            h[O] = (d[O] ? m - h[Y] * 12 : 0);
            f = new Date(f.getTime());
            var n = (f.getDate() == i);
            var o = x._getDaysInMonth(f.getFullYear() + h[Y], f.getMonth() + h[O]);
            if (f.getDate() > o) {
                f.setDate(o)
            }
            f.setFullYear(f.getFullYear() + h[Y]);
            f.setMonth(f.getMonth() + h[O]);
            if (n) {
                f.setDate(o)
            }
        }
        var p = Math.floor((g.getTime() - f.getTime()) / 1000);
        var q = function (a, b) {
            h[a] = (d[a] ? Math.floor(p / b) : 0);
            p -= h[a] * b
        };
        q(W, 604800);
        q(D, 86400);
        q(H, 3600);
        q(M, 60);
        q(S, 1);
        if (p > 0 && !c._since) {
            var r = [1, 12, 4.3482, 7, 24, 60, 60];
            var s = S;
            var t = 1;
            for (var u = S; u >= Y; u--) {
                if (d[u]) {
                    if (h[s] >= t) {
                        h[s] = 0;
                        p = 1
                    }
                    if (p > 0) {
                        h[u]++;
                        p = 0;
                        s = u;
                        t = 1
                    }
                }
                t *= r[u]
            }
        }
        if (e) {
            for (var u = Y; u <= S; u++) {
                if (e && h[u]) {
                    e--
                } else if (!e) {
                    h[u] = 0
                }
            }
        }
        return h
    }
});
var w = ['getTimes'];

function isNotChained(a, b) {
    if (a == 'option' && (b.length == 0 || (b.length == 1 && typeof b[0] == 'string'))) {
        return true
    }
    return $.inArray(a, w) > -1
}
$.fn.countdown = function (a) {
    var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (isNotChained(a, b)) {
        return x['_' + a + 'Plugin'].apply(x, [this[0]].concat(b))
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        if (typeof a == 'string') {
            if (!x['_' + a + 'Plugin']) {
                throw 'Unknown command: ' + a;
            }
            x['_' + a + 'Plugin'].apply(x, [this].concat(b))
        } else {
            x._attachPlugin(this, a || {})
        }
    })
};
var x = $.countdown = new Countdown()})(jQuery);
```

for some reason the code gets up here...

*Update*
Sorry, forgot the "real thing" :P

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Countdown date
    var end = new Date("March, 25, 2013");
    // Countdown handler
    var countdownObj = {
        until : end,
        layout : '{dn}<span> {dl} </span>{hnn}<span> {hl} </span>{mnn}<span> {ml} </span>{snn}<span> {sl}</span>',
        labels: ['years', 'months', 'weeks', 'days', 'hours', 'min', 'sec'],
        labels1: ['year', 'month', 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'min', 'sec'],
        expiryText : "Countdown is complete!"
    };
    $('#countdown').countdown(countdownObj);
});
```

Comment: I won't answer a question with a curse, but I like the irony of the "build layout" not having layout.  Did you intend it as a joke?

Comment: It looks like you've just included the source code from some jQuery plugin in your post.  Where's your code using the plugin that isn't working, and can you provide a link to the plugin source?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using a modified version of [**this jQuery plugin**](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).  I don't know exactly why it isn't working, but when I linked to a fresh copy of the [**live script**](http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js), it works great ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxDDa/1/)).

```
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

I would recommend downloading a fresh copy of the plugin and adding it to your project to see if that resolves the issue.